# How to tell if pins are I/O from schematic?

Tags: schematics, pins, configuration

I am using the Fusion360 New Electronics Library to reproduce the footprint/schematic of the [NHS3152-AZ](https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/NXP-Semiconductors/NHS3152-A1Z?qs=uj7TeyS2Sj%2FtTZtkVBvC3w%3D%3D).

Following along from [Tutorial: Creating electronic components with Fusion 360](https://youtu.be/zqar0XWtFaY?t=489), at min: 8:09 they assign pin configuration values (I/O, I, O) by cross-referencing with the datasheet.

However with the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NHS3152.pdf) for NHS3152(pg6) you can see that pins have 2 names, eg: PIO0_9 & MOSI, with 2 different pin configurations: I/O and I.

[image: NHS3152 DATASHEET PIN CONFIGURATIONS]

What should I eneter for the pins? I/O each time?

I have a schematic of a DEMO, which is configured correctly.

[image: NHS3152DEMO schematic]

From this schematic, can you understand the I/O pin configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is configured by the software running on the microcontroller. You should make your schematic representative of what the function you will be using will be. In the *DEMO* schematic, they've listed both as they don't know ahead of time what the user's software is going to do.

Beware that there can be some issues with specifying a pin direction/function this if the pin is configured out of reset as something different and you expect ERC to flag any incompatibility.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the pin I/O assignemnt will have no effect on the fabrication of the PCB ? I am planning on getting PCBway or another company to fabricate some PCB with this chip on it.

Comment: @leoelectrics - no, the fabricator does not care about or have any knowledge of the logical function of your circuit.

Comment: So maybe i should put NC to all the pins i am not using? 
I only want to use LA-LB ( for the antenna), ANA_0, ANA_5. And connect to ground

Comment: @leoelectrics - the schematic is the _logical representation_ of the circuit. Good practice is to explicitly put pins as NC if you're not connecting them. ERC can be configured to find unconnected pins. The physical pad will still be on the PCB, but not connected to anything.

Comment: As far as I see, the designer put all possible pin names on pins.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - yes, you're right, mis-read that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the schematic, each pin has to be labeled as per the functions/label given in the datasheet. If a pin has many labels, mention them. And if you are not using the pin, give  Not Connected NC mark in the schematic. Sometimes, some pins should be tied to VDD or  pulled up or pulled down as per the datasheet if we are not using them.

If you are not sure about which function is used for  a particular pin in firmware, just interface the line with whatever device you wanted to ( ie) concentrate on the hardware  perspective.

We cannot tell the exact function of a pin when it has many functions, unless we know the design requirements. Based on the requirement, firmware development  will be done.